# Creating a new sql table where columns are derived from another sql table

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have one sql table that contains keywords and occurrences likes so (though the occurrences are not important):

```
____________
dog     | 3 |
____________
rat     | 7 |
____________
cat     | 9 |
____________
rat     | 2 |
____________
```

and what I want to do is create a new table where each column is a unique keyword from the first table as well as an id. Like so

```
_______________________
randomID|rat |cat |dog|
______________________
```

I'm not too sure how to go about doing this. I am writing to the first table using python, but if I can do this in MySQL workbench with a create Table that would be preferable!
Thank you!

Comment: Unless you know the keywords in advance, you have to use dynamic SQL.  And if you have to use dynamic SQL, you might as well use Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might work

```
Insert into tablename (cat,rat,dog) values (select cat from table,select rat from table,select dog from table)
```

And id you want to create as dynamic